# VBA Code Help - Need to add a line for each missing date and copy data from cells below

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I have the below code to add a line for each missing date then update column D with the missing date but I also want the new line to copy the data from the cells below for columns A to c and E to L.

Currently I end up with a worksheet like this
[image]

The VBA code is:

```
Dim wks As Worksheet
Set wks = Worksheets("NAV_REPORT")

Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Range("D2").End(xlDown).Row

For i = lastRow To 2 Step -1
    curcell = wks.Cells(i, 4).Value
    prevcell = wks.Cells(i - 1, 4).Value

    Do Until curcell - 1 <= prevcell
        wks.Rows(i).Insert xlShiftDown

        curcell = wks.Cells(i + 1, 4) - 1
        wks.Cells(i, 4).Value = curcell
    Loop
Next i
```

any suggestions for updating the above code to fill up from the cells below?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the inserted row to be identical to the row above, all you need to do is to copy the row above and insert that like follows:

```
wks.Rows(i).Copy
wks.Rows(i).Insert xlShiftDown
```

This will insert the exact data on the previous row and the rest of your code will amend the date as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly...

```
Sub test()
dim c as range: dim dif 
Set c = Range("D2")
Do Until c.Value = ""
    dif = DateDiff("d", c.Value, c.Offset(1, 0).Value)
    If dif > 1 Then
        With c.Offset(1, -3)
            .EntireRow.Copy
            Range(.Cells, .Offset(dif - 2, 0)).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        End With
        c.AutoFill Destination:=Range(c, c.Offset(dif - 1, 0)), Type:=xlFillDefault
        Set c = c.Offset(dif, 0)
    Else
        Set c = c.Offset(1, 0)
    End If
Loop
End Sub
```

The sub assumes that there is no blank cell in between the rows of data in column D.

> the new line to copy the data from the cells **below** for columns A to c
> and E to L.

the "below" here is the yellow and orange before running the sub.

[image] ===> [image]