# VBA - Loop wont add dates for start of the month

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have a macro that filters data by each unique value in column A and then adds lines for any missing dates. The Macro will only add the missing dates for the start of the month to the first group. The rest of the missing dates are added to all groups without any issues.

I think the issue is the 'If I = 2 then prevcell = start_date'. Is there any way to fix this so each time the macro filters it adds the missing dates at the start of the group even when not in line 2?

```
'Sub Macro1()

Dim aNames As Variant, Itm As Variant

With Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, Unique:=False
aNames = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlVisible).Value
For Each Itm In aNames
  .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Itm
  
  'Do whatever you want with an individual name here
  Call Macro2
  
Next Itm
.AutoFilter
End With

Sub Macro2()


Dim wks As Worksheet, ssh As Worksheet
Set wks = Worksheets("NAV_REPORT_FSIGLOB1")
Set ssh = Worksheets("SUMMARY")
Dim lastRow As Long, start_date As Date, end_date As Date, curcell As Date

lastRow = wks.Range("D2").End(xlDown).Row
start_date = ssh.Range("A2") - 1
end_date = ssh.Range("B2")

With wks.Cells(lastRow, 4)
    If .Value < end_date Then
        .EntireRow.Copy
        .EntireRow.Insert xlShiftDown
        lastRow = lastRow + 1
        .Value = end_date
    End If
End With

For i = lastRow To 2 Step -1
    curcell = wks.Cells(i, 4).Value
    If i = lastRow Then curcell = end_date
    prevcell = wks.Cells(i - 1, 4).Value
    If i = 2 Then prevcell = start_date
    Do Until curcell - 1 <= prevcell
        wks.Rows(i).Copy
        wks.Rows(i).Insert xlShiftDown
        curcell = wks.Cells(i + 1, 4) - 1
        wks.Cells(i, 4).Value = curcell
    Loop
Next i`
```

Comment: If you just want to fill the date series in column D, maybe try to use `datediff` to get the difference number of the day. Then insert the copied row as much as that number and use autofill to have the date series in column D. Just curious, what did you mean by "_adds lines for any missing dates_" ? Example : dtS = 10-Jan-23, dtE = 20-Jan-23. if the value of the curcel (the `.Cells(lastRow, 4)`) = 3-Jan-23, then what is the missing dates ? If curcel = 28-Jan-23, then what is the missing dates ? If curcel = 15-Jan-23, then what is the missing dates ?

Comment: Why you don't say that the macro in your question is not yours but from mr. CLR who answer your question in this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75211981/vba-code-help-add-a-line-for-each-missing-date-with-the-start-and-end-date-def? And instead have a look to the answer of your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75172779/vba-code-help-need-to-add-a-line-for-each-missing-date-and-copy-data-from-cell, you make a similar question here ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer below assumes that all your three questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75172779/vba-code-help-need-to-add-a-line-for-each-missing-date-and-copy-data-from-cell/75180868#75180868), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75211981/vba-code-help-add-a-line-for-each-missing-date-with-the-start-and-end-date-def) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75235164/vba-loop-wont-add-dates-for-start-of-the-month) is actually the same which have the same expected result.

> I have a macro that filters data by each unique value in column A

The code below is not involving a unique value and a filtering.

> The **start and end date** would need updated monthly so needs to be
> easily changed e.g. cells A2 and B2 on the "Summary" worksheet.

The code will involve a start date (dtS) value and end date value (dtE).

> adds lines for any missing dates

The row addition regarding the dtS will happen only if the **first** value in column D is bigger then dtS. If the first value in column D is smaller than the dtS then it does nothing

The row addition regarding the dtE will happen only if the **last** value in column D is smaller then dtE. If the last value in column D is bigger than the dtE then it does nothing.

before running the sub :
[image]

In a condition where `dtS = "02-Oct-22": dtE = "20-Oct-22"`, If yellow column D value is 2 Oct 22, then no process is performed. If blue column D value is 23 Oct 22, then no process is performed.

The expected result :

- yellow will be 2 rows, where column D value is from 2 to 3 Oct 22.
- orange will be 3 rows, where column D value is from 8 to 10 Oct 22.
- green will be 5 rows, where column D value is from 13 to 17 Oct 22.
- blue will be 3 rows, where column D value is from 18 to 20 Oct 22.

[image]

There will be three section in the code.
The first is a loop which already mentioned in the answer of your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75172779/vba-code-help-need-to-add-a-line-for-each-missing-date-and-copy-data-from-cell/75180868#75180868).
The second and the third is additional code to involve the dtS and dtE.

```
Sub test()
Dim dtS As Date: Dim dtE As Date
Dim c As Range: Dim dif As Integer

Set c = Range("D2")
dtS = "02-Oct-22": dtE = "20-Oct-22"

'same code in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75172779/vba-code-help-need-to-add-a-line-for-each-missing-date-and-copy-data-from-cell/75180868#75180868
Do While c.Offset(1, 0).Value <> ""
    dif = DateDiff("d", c.Value, c.Offset(1, 0).Value)
    If dif > 1 Then
        With c.Offset(1, -3)
            .EntireRow.Copy
            Range(.Cells, .Offset(dif - 2, 0)).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        End With
        c.AutoFill Destination:=Range(c, c.Offset(dif - 1, 0)), Type:=xlFillDefault
        Set c = c.Offset(dif, 0)
    Else
        Set c = c.Offset(1, 0)
    End If
Loop

'check the dtS in column D first value
Set c = Range("D2")
If dtS < CDate(c.Value) Then
    dif = DateDiff("d", dtS, c.Value): c.Value = dtS
        With c.Offset(0, -3)
        .EntireRow.Copy
        Range(.Cells, .Offset(dif - 1, 0)).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        End With
    Set c = Range("D2")
    c.AutoFill Destination:=c.Resize(dif + 1, 1), Type:=xlFillDefault
End If

'check the dtE in column D last value
Set c = Range("D2").End(xlDown)
If dtE > CDate(c.Value) Then
    addr = c.Address: dif = DateDiff("d", c.Value, dtE)
    With c.Offset(0, -3)
        .EntireRow.Copy
        Range(.Cells, .Offset(dif - 1, 0)).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    End With
    With Range(addr)
    .AutoFill Destination:=.Resize(dif + 1, 1), Type:=xlFillDefault
    End With
End If

End Sub
```

Again, the sub above is based on guessing from all of your three questions. Because in your first question, you don't mentioned about start date and end date at all. In the second question you mentioned :

> Could someone help with rewriting the code so it adds all dates that
> are missing between a **start and end date**. The start and end date would
> need updated monthly so needs to be easily changed e.g. cells A2 and
> B2 on the "Summary" worksheet

And in this question, you mentioned ONLY about the start date.

> add the missing dates for the **start of the month**

Please note that the answer is based on the data in your [second question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75211981/vba-code-help-add-a-line-for-each-missing-date-with-the-start-and-end-date-def), where your data is something like this
[image: this]

which your expected result is like this
[image: this]